# angularjs reload page but setting new URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href, reload

Hi im trying to use `$window.location.reload()` but i need to use a new URL so this URL have the `routeParams` that a service use.

here is my piece of code:

```
 $window.location.href += "/" + $scope.var1 + "/" + $scope.var2;
 $window.location.reload(true);
```

the thing with this approach is that the url change but when reload it set it to the default route of my app taking out the href i set.

Answer (score 0):

it is a good practice to always use angular services, try to never use window or jquery functions, angular provides them all, in this case i think you should try with the `$location` service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
$location.path('your url')
```

if all you need is reload the current path better use the `$route` service

```
$route.reload();
```

this will only reload your ngView, if you need to reload all the page

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: yeah, but this way the page don't reload, so i need to clear all my scope manually

Comment: then use the $route service `$route.reload();`

Comment: i tryed with `$route.reload()` and didn't work and with `$window.location.reload()` don't take the new URL with the route params